# Jest test: Pass nested object to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a functional component like this:

```
const ImageScreen = (props: any) => {
  const images: object[] = [];
  props.navigation.state.params.images.forEach((image: any) =>
    //some code
  );

  return (
    <View style={CommonStyles.normalPage}>
      // some code
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then I write Jest to test this component:

```
test(`renders correctly`, () => {
  const props = {
    navigation: {
      state: {
        params: {
          images: [
            { url: "../sample-images/sample1.jpg" },
            { url: "../sample-images/sample2.jpg" },
          ],
          index: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const component = renderer.create(<ImageScreen props={props} />);
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But I always got error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

I'm new to both Jest and React Native, so not sure if I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You've passed a prop called "props" into the component. This is accessible as a property "props" in the component's function.

What you wanted to do was add all the (nested) props to the component, rather than a prop called "props".

Try the following instead:

```
const component = renderer.create(<ImageScreen {...props} />);
```

Comment: I did as your suggestion, but this time Jest gave error: "TypeError: success is not a function....getSize: jest.fn((uri, success) => process.nextTick(() => success(320, 240))),"